# how to set five button in toolbar with same size?

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iPhone I have working on all button set in toolbar with same size give any suggestion and source code

Answer (score 0):

You must build a NSMutableArray and put 5 UIBarButtonItem in it, set theirs properties like you want and then set this Array in the ToolBarItems like this:

```
NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *myButton1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toolbarButtonPressed1:)];
[buttonsArray addObject:myButton1];
//here you set the other properties for your first button

// and then you do the same for your other buttons


[self setToolbarItems:buttonsArray animated:YES];
```

of course you must have declare a ToolBar before :)